# Laravel multiple count in 1 Query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-4.2

Im new to this Framework, i dont know how to optimize it using db::raw count and aliases and display it to my blade.php using @foreach

im trying to optimize my code, my goals is to count pallet_conditions and store it to my aliases, i dont want to count it one by one like what i did on this code

this is my code not optimize:

```
//computing the total rapairable
$repairable_total = DB::table('liip_psrm_items')
->where('psrm_items_id', '=' , $psrm_maintenance->id)
->where('pallet_condition', '=', 1)
->count();
//REPAIRABLE

//computing the total good pallets
$good_total = DB::table('liip_psrm_items')
->where('psrm_items_id', '=' , $psrm_maintenance->id)
->where('pallet_condition', '=', 0)
->count();
//GOOD
```

this is the code, what i wanted to learn. just to minimize, and use aliases

```
$result = DB::table('liip_psrm_items')
->select(DB::raw('COUNT(liip_psrm_items.pallet_condition = 0 ) AS condition_1',
                 'COUNT(liip_psrm_items.pallet_condition = 1 ) AS condition_2'))                      
                ->where('psrm_items_id', '=' , $psrm_maintenance->id)
                ->get();
```

Comment: Your Laravel code looks fine to me.  What is your actual question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to pass a closure like so:

```
$results = DB::table('liip_psrm_items')
->where('psrm_items_id', '=' , $psrm_maintenance->id)
->where(function($query){
   $query->where('pallet_condition', 1)
      ->orWhere('pallet_condition', 0);
})->count();
```

Comment: @YasserCHENIK You can file a bug at https://github.com/laravel/laravel if you feel that `where` method is useless.

Comment: in other words : [ i will wake up tomorrow if you = "like it" or if you ="don't like it" ] is equivalent to [ i will wake up tomorrow ] because it's boolean with all possible conditions inside it, so your `where` statement is indeed useless my friend :l

Answer (score 4):

To count at multiple condition I used this approach

```
 $lastMonthInvoices = Invoice::select(DB::raw("(COUNT(*)) as count"), DB::raw('SUM(total) as total'),'status')
        ->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subMonth())
        ->groupBy('status')
        ->get();
```

i got the result with  groupBy Status and in each group total number of records as count & also their sum as total

[image: sample of one group]

[image]

these two snaps are of one query result

Answer (score 3):

You can't use single query for two different results, which has totally opposite conditions.

Case 1. You are trying to count the items where pallet_condition = 1;

Case 2. You are trying to count the items where pallet_condition = 0;

Now you want to merge these two cases into single query, which is impossible...

So, For these two cases, you have to use either separate queries ( what you did already )

or you can use single query to grab all the items and then use PHP to separate them.

Like:

```
$total_items = DB::table('liip_psrm_items')
   ->where('psrm_items_id', '=' , $psrm_maintenance->id)
   ->get();

$repairable_count = count(array_filter($total_items, function($item){
   return (bool)$item->pallet_condition;
}));

$good_count = count(array_filter($total_items, function($item){
   return !(bool)$item->pallet_condition; //just inverse of the above condition
}));
```

i hope this might help.

Comment: thank for the suggestion @jaskaran appriciate it. 
the above answer jonjie solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

You can, first `group by`, then get `count`

Like :

```php
DB::table('liip_psrm_items')
  ->groupBy('pallet_condition')
  ->select('pallet_condition', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
  ->get();
```